# matplotlib selecting wrong font style/weight

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I want to change the default font used in matplotlib plots to be Segoe UI under Windows. I can do so by altering `rcParams` like so

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Segoe UI'] + matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif']
matplotlib.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'normal'
```

This works, however the weight of the font appears to be wrong. Using the following code I can confirm that matplotlib is picking up the 'Semibold' version of the font rather than the 'Regular' variant that I would expect from setting `matplotlib.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'normal'`.

```
from matplotlib.font_manager import findfont, FontProperties
font = findfont(FontProperties(family=['sans-serif']))
print font

>>> c:\windows\fonts\seguisb.ttf
```

How can I force matplotlib to use the 'Regular' variant? Is this possible with `rcParams`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a hack that fixes the problem with Segoe UI without needing to set kwargs every time...

For some reason, the tf2font module (which is a .pyd) attributes a font weight of 400 to the Segoe UI Black, Ultralight, Light and Semi-bold fonts, which really should have a font weight of 1000, 100, 200 and 500, respectively.

**First delete your fontList.json file.** (For me it was in .matplotlib\fontList.json).

**Then, right before this line in font_manager.py:**

```
return FontEntry(font.fname, name, style, variant, weight, stretch, size)
```

**Insert the following code:**

```
switch = lambda x: {
    #Correct the font-weight for these fonts
    'seguibl.ttf': 1000,
    'segouisl.ttf': 100,
    'seguisb.ttf':500,
    'segoeuil.ttf':200
}[x]

f =  os.path.split(font.fname)[1]
if f in ['seguibl.ttf', 'segouisl.ttf', 'seguisb.ttf', 'segoeuil.ttf']:
    weight = switch(f)
```

**The end result will look like:**

```
switch = lambda x: {
    #Correct the font-weight for these fonts
    'seguibl.ttf': 1000,
    'segouisl.ttf': 100,
    'seguisb.ttf':500,
    'segoeuil.ttf':200
}[x]

f =  os.path.split(font.fname)[1]
if f in ['seguibl.ttf', 'segouisl.ttf', 'seguisb.ttf', 'segoeuil.ttf']:
    weight = switch(f)
return FontEntry(font.fname, name, style, variant, weight, stretch, size)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that matplotlib selects out of all the "Segoe UI" fonts the bold one for no reason. I fear that you cannot do much about this on the rcParams level.

If someone finds a solution to this issue I'd really appreciate it as well.

Until then, here is a workaround using the `fontproperties` kwarg.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
path = r'C:\Windows\Fonts\segoeui.ttf'
path1 = r'C:\Windows\Fonts\seguisb.ttf'
path2 = r'C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf'
for i, p in enumerate([path,path1,path2]):
    prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=p)
    tx = 'Text in {font},\n{path}\nweight {weight}\nvariant {var}'
    tx = tx.format(font=prop.get_name(), weight=prop.get_weight(), var=prop.get_variant(), path=p)
    ax.text(0.1,0.1+i*0.3,tx, fontproperties=prop, size=18)
plt.show()
```

The disadvantage clearly is that you need to manually put it everywhere, instead of putting it once in the header.